# Why does this Haskell code become invalid if I add spaces?

Tags: haskell, syntax, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Sorry for probably a noob question.

I'm getting this:

```
Prelude> all (\x -> x==1) ([n | n <- [1..20]])
False
Prelude> all (\x -> x == 1) ([n | n <- [1..20]])

<interactive>:17:44:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Prelude>
```

I.e. `x==1` works, but if I change this to `x == 1` it doesn't. But why is that? E.g. `1 == 1` seem to work fine.

Compiler Version:

```
$ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
```

Added screenshot for proof; it's hard to see but you can see the input line doesn't contain anything weird.

[image]

Comment: It works for me...  What version of GHC are you using?

Comment: I have $ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3

Comment: It works for me too. I tried turning on any syntax extension that might reasonably be related and I couldn't find one that breaks it.

Comment: Would you mind copy/pasting the code you have above directly into GHCi and trying it out?  Those spaces shouldn't have any impact at all on the parser.  Maybe you missed a parentheses at the end when you typed it into the shell, but got it right on SO?

Comment: Ah it only occurs in the Sublime Haskell REPL! I'll file a ticket for them then. Thanks for testing!

Comment: Also curious: your example doesn't have 44 columns, but the error claims to be in the 44th column?

Comment: @DougMcClean: I'm pretty certain it's a Sublime plugin problem. I filed an issue.

Comment: Requested to close the question since it's not related to Haskell.

Comment: @didierc but it is, though: it's in the Haskell ecosystem.

Comment: I think this question is definitely on topic: it was an obscure problem *with* Haskell, even if, in the end, it was actually the fault of Sublime. Besides that, questions about tools often used by programmers are on topic anyhow!

Comment: I meant the issue isn't bound to a problem with the language (or ghc). It's not completely off topic, I agree.

Comment: I would suggest making the comment "it's a problem in sublime" an answer for now (just so that this question stays around but is flaged as resolved)

Comment: anyway, i would use (==1) instead of (\x -> x == 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this behaviour only occurs in Sublime Haskell REPL plugin. I've filed a ticket for this.